# Why does Harrell Argue for "Ignoring Y during data reduction"?

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, unsupervised-learning

In *Regression Modeling Strategies* page 79 (4.7 Data Reduction) reads:

> Data reduction is aimed at reducing the number of parameters to estimate in the model, without distorting statistical inference for the parameters. This is accomplished by ignoring Y during data reduction. Manipulations of X in unsupervised learning may result in a loss of information for predicting Y , but when the information loss is small, the gain in power and reduction of overfitting more than offset the loss

Does unsupervised learning not increase the risk of throwing out relevant variables? How do you argue to a researcher/PI who has no stat background that losing those is more than offset by the gains in power and alleviation of overfitting?

Lastly are there situations where this trade is not worth it? If the researcher primarily is concerned with figuring out the "right" variables, for instance.

I trust that the text's advice is sound but I want to understand it well enough that I can explain to a skeptical lay audience.

Comment: "Lastly are there situations where this trade is not worth it?". I would argue that this is clearly the case in the context of a designed experiment, where there *is* no structure in the X's beyond that which the experimenter has themselves imposed, and a useful reduction can only be accomplished with reference to the Y's.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All the answers are terrific.  I'll just add a "big picture" note.  We use data reduction not because it's perfect but when the alternative is a disaster.  One of the worst things you can do with data is to take a huge number of collinear features and predict to find the "right" features that predict Y.  The data have no chance of finding the right variables in that setting.  Data reduction reduces the problem to an analysis that lives without your sample size and collinearity limitations.

As a side note, sparse PCA is one of the more promising data reduction methods and gives a better interpretation than regular PCA in most cases.

Comment: The question I've had about this that I was hoping would get addressed in the answers here relates to your idea that, if someone uses stepwise regression to select features (major issues with that, sure, but it can be done) and then wants to assess model fit with adjusted $R^2$, the degrees of freedom should be calculated based on the number of candidate features instead of the number of selected features, yet that does not seem to be a concern when the feature reduction excludes the outcome variable. Why is that? (Perhaps this warrants its own question specific to this issue.)

Comment: Because if the candidate features do not include a response variable the number of papers estimate in the prediction model is the the dimensionality of the reduced space.

Comment: Thank you for this, it really helps with the intuition. So, in general any quest for finding "best variables" or "which variables belong in a model" is not only futile but actively bad? So often researchers are asking me "pick the best variables". But it seems the answer is "that's a bad idea" and that we should either keep what we have, have a field expert choose, or reduce through unsupervised techniques?

Answer (score 17):

> Does unsupervised learning not increase the risk of throwing out relevant variables?

As Frank says, "Manipulations of X in unsupervised learning may result in a loss of information for predicting Y" so yes, there is a risk of losing some information.  But, again to Frank's point, when the loss is small then the gain in other avenues can be large.

A different way to think about this is the alternative strategy: use Y to select variables that predict Y.  That seems like cheating — study the answers to find the questions you need to study for to get a good score on the test. There are plenty of examples of this being a bad idea.  Frank is a notable opponent of things like stepwise regression, and so I'm sure you can find something he has written on the topic to demonstrate why using Y to select X is a bad idea.

> In Regression Modeling Strategies page 79 (4.7 Data Reduction) reads:

> Data reduction is aimed at reducing the number of parameters to estimate in the model, without distorting statistical inference for the parameters. This is accomplished by ignoring Y during data reduction. Manipulations of X in unsupervised learning may result in a loss of information for predicting Y , but when the information loss is small, the gain in power and reduction of overfitting more than offset the loss

> Does unsupervised learning not increase the risk of throwing out relevant variables? How do you argue to a researcher/PI who has no stat background that losing those is more than offset by the gains in power and alleviation of overfitting?

> Lastly are there situations where this trade is not worth it?

I would like to think that unsupervised methods are not worth it when interpretability is a key issue.  PCA is an illustrative example.  PCA will take linear combinations of the features, but how am I to interpret the first PC?  It is a mix of many variables, and so the typical interpretation from a linear model (*a unit increase in x results in a $\beta$ change in the outcome*) does not easily map onto our original variables.

Comment: IMHO "use Y to select variables that predict Y. That seems like cheating" is too strong since that is not different from what predictive models do (after all, coeffients can become 0 which means the variate in question is "deselected"). The important point is that data reduction is part of the predictive model, and must be accounted for appropriately. That may be *easier* if only X information is used at this point compared to using X and Y, but in general, also unsupervised data compression must be taken into account appropriately.

Comment: There are other unsupervised methods than just PCA. For instance, In _Regression Modelling Strategies_ Harrell uses Variable Clustering to find closely related variables that explain the same information. It should be easy to explain that if two variables are measuring the same thing (e.g., very highly correlated), it might be waste to measure both and introduce problem of multicolinearity into a model.

Harrell also uses redundancy analysis to find if one can predict one variable from another. The same logic as above applies.

Comment: In both cases, we ignore Y and reduce the parameter space (X) by removing redundant variables. Essentially as PCA would, we are not transforming anything and keeping high interpretability.

For instance, I have found that explaining variable clustering to non-statistician (using tree visualisation) is very easy (at least, that's how it felt from my end).

Answer (score 10):

Harrell gives you the reason why in your quote

> Data reduction is aimed at reducing the number of parameters to
> estimate in the model, *without distorting statistical inference for
> the parameters*. This is accomplished by ignoring Y during data
> reduction.

(my italics)

In the summarisation at [Regression modelling strategies web](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/multivar):

> Data reduction is completely masked to $\mathbf{Y}$, which is precisely why it
> does not distort estimates, standard errors, $\mathbf{P}$-values, or confidence
> limits

If you select variables based on Y ( eg eyeballing scatter plots, univariate correlations, stepwise regression), then your standard statistical significance tests will be inflated. Go to  eg [spurious correlations eg margarine consumption predicts divorce rate in maine](http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious/correlation/5920_per-capita-consumption-of-margarine_correlates-with_the-divorce-rate-in-maine)

where plenty of nonsensical statistically significant correlations are plotted.

Tyler Viglen explains:

> Data dredging: I have 25,156 variables in my database. I compare all
> these variables against each other to find ones that randomly match
> up. That's 632,824,336 correlation calculations! This is called “data
> dredging.” Instead of starting with a hypothesis and testing it, I
> instead abused the data to see what correlations shake out. It’s a
> dangerous way to go about analysis, because any sufficiently large
> dataset will yield strong correlations completely at random.

If you then run statistical software to calculate the statistical significance, you will achieve very high numbers, because the software is answering the question how likely is it that a randomly generated set of points could generate such a high correlation, whereas what you would want answered is something like "what is the probability that the best correlation from 632 million random generated datasets is above 0.99". You could theoretically create bootstrapped data sets, where you included your selection process in the bootstrap process, but eg if its manual selection this is obviously impractical.

you certainly can use a supervised method to do this data investigation, but you have to do it on an *independent* data set. eg split the data in half, do your digging in half the data set, do the modelling with the selected data on the other half of the data.  Frank Harrell's views are I believe coming from the medical field, where data is limited, and halving your data set is a colossal waste of data (and so a much greater drop in power).

In a prediction context, again any of this variable selection should be done on the training data, and you test the eventual model's performance on a test set.

Comment: The book is freely available [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/).

Comment: @COOLSerdash its some summarisation of the book as far as I can see.

Comment: You have to buy the book and it is worth every penny. That is Dr. Harrell’s companion site.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I understand it, the major reason for not using $Y$ in data reduction is that much theory is based on the crucial assumption that this is *not* done, and doing it will violate the theory in a critical manner. The simplest example is the standard distribution theory for LS regression coefficient estimators and the tests and confidence intervals based on it. These will be hugely overoptimistic (i.e., assume far more precision than we indeed have) if the $Y$ has been used for data reduction before.

Furthermore, data-driven assessment of predictive power such as cross-validation is often run ignoring the use of $Y$ for dimension reduction, i.e., the selected lower dimensional representation of the $X$-space is used without accounting for the fact that there was data dependent selection for it before. Once more, this will lead to an overoptimistic assessment of prediction strength. In machine learning this is known as "information leakage". In fact it can be avoided using techniques such as double cross-validation, double bootstrap, or data splitting plus cross-validation on data not used for dimension reduction.

That said, it is in fact true that unsupervised dimension reduction is prone to losing valuable information that supervised dimension reduction when done correctly does not lose. I (and students of mine) have compared, for example, PCA on $X$-space with partial least squares (PLS; which uses the $Y$ for dimension reduction) in some projects, carefully doing the cross-validation in such a way that information leakage is avoided, and have found that PLS outperforms PCA more often than not. This shouldn't be all too surprising as PLS uses more relevant information than PCA (in fact the concept of "information leakage" implies that there *is* information in the first place). So ultimately, if your major aim is predictive power, the unsupervised route may not be better. On the other hand, if you plan to run and interpret standard significance tests, using the $Y$ for dimension reduction will for sure mess things up. Note that Harrell himself (who is occasionally active on this site) has stated that he has in the meantime become more Bayesian than he was writing that book. Maybe now he'd say "don't use such significance tests regardless of whether dimension reduction is done in a supervised or unsupervised manner", which would take away a reason to do it in an unsupervised manner. But then information leakage can be a problem in Bayesian analysis as well.

Comment: Is there a paper out there with a PCA-PLS comparison?

Comment: No, sorry, it was just a number of student projects and examples I did for teaching.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I'd expect such comparisons to exist in the chemometrics literature, likely from decades ago. Peter Wentzell's paper from CILS 2003 Comparison of principal components regression and partial least squares regression through generic simulations of complex mixtures has a large literature review part which may be a good start: https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0169-7439(02)00138-7

Comment: also, you may be interested in Alejando Olivieri's work on figures of merit/uncertainty for models like PCR or PLS. https://doi.org/10.1021/ac501786u or https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-443-13261-2.00016-3 may be a good start.

Comment: @ChristianHennig: I'm curious about data leakage mechanisms that in practice occur with PLSR but not with PCR? (PCA as data compression being done before/outside any resampling/cross validation is in my experience a pretty usual candidate for data leakage and as a result the typical overfitting/overoptimistic bias as well)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX The thing is that in standard regression models the $y$ is random and the $x$ is fixed. This means that PCA does not use the random information, and more to the point, no information on how the $y$ is linked to the $x$. It does use information about the $x$, so if you call that "data leakage" I can't really object, however (without attempting to prove it;-) the leakage that looks really harmful is the leakage regarding how the $y$ depends on the $x$.